# Merging Dataframe within a for loop

Tags: pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I tried to perform my self-created function on a for loop, but it does not work as expected.

Some remarks in advance:

ma_strategy is my function and requires three inputs
ticker_list is a list with strings
result is a pandas Dataframe with 7 columns and I can call the column 'return_cum' with result['return_cum']. The rows of this column are containing floating point numbers.

These for loops doesn't work:

```
for i in ticker_list:
    result = ma_strategy(i, 20, 5)
    x = result['return_cum']
    sample_returns = pd.DataFrame
    y = pd.merge(x.to_frame(),sample_returns, left_index=True)

for i in ticker_list:
    result = ma_strategy(i, 20, 5)
    x = result[['return_cum']]
    sample_returns = pd.DataFrame
    y = pd.concat([sample_returns, x], axis=1)
```

My intention is the following:

The for loop should iterate over the items in my ticker_list and should save the 'return_cum' columns in x. Then the 'return_cum' columns should be stored in y together so that at the end I get a DataFrame with all the 'return_cum' columns of my ticker list.

How can I achieve that goal? I tried pd.concoat and merge, but nothing works.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean they "don't work"? Do they yield the wrong result? If you have a specific error you get, please post it.

Comment: If I use pd.concat I get an TypeError: TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Comment: And with merge: ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'type'>